# c++, convert std::string to uint8_t

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stdstring, uint8t

in the c++ solution I am working on I have a function that returns a string reference.  like `const std::string& getData() const {return mData;}` and the mData is `std::string mData;`.  now I want to convert it to `uint8_t` array to pass it to another function pointer.

```
/* in another header -> typedef uint8_t  U8; */
const std::string& d = frame.getData();
U8 char_array[d.length()];
/* here I want to put the d char by char in char_array*/
```

the `strcpy` is deprecated so I am using `strcpy_s` like `strcpy_s(char_array, d);`

which of course I get `couldn't match type char(&)[_size] against unsigned char[]`

and also static or reinterpret casting to `char*` does not work too.

Comment: since when is `strcpy` deprecated?

Comment: What's in that string?

Comment: is it possible that you are talking about c not c++? c has `strcpy_s` but not c++ afaik

Comment: @user463035818 MSVC prints a deprecation warning for strcpy, since strcpy_s exists and is safer.

Comment: @user463035818 please do not take the conversation somewhere irrelevant, a simple search gives you lots of results of deprecated functions because of being unsafe

Comment: Do you want to give out a complete new copy of a uint8_t or just a reference?

Comment: @Superlokkus a complete new copy I think would be better for my case

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel  it can be any thing but for sure not more than 8 characters, for instance `*e Øà±┤/` is one string

Comment: You can use `std::string::data()` to get a pointer to the string's data.

Comment: `strcpy_s` is not standard c++, but MSVC specific, didnt know that before and had to look it up, dont know why you think that is irrelevant...

Comment: @user463035818 `strcpy_s` is standard as of C11.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel I know, and that is C not C++

Comment: For Unicode, use wchar_t ( std::wstring for portability) , for MCB use char ( or std::string), why uin8_t ?

Comment: @seccpur I am adding some features to a protocol DLL which was developed more than 10 years ago, so that was their design and I cannot change

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a vector, what you are writing are VLAs, which is not valid C++ (`U8 char_array[d.length()]`). then use `std::copy`.

```
const std::string& d = frame.getData();
std::vector<U8> char_array(d.length() + 1, 0);
```

The question is if you need to have the end of  string `\0` or not, so it's going to be d.length()+1 if you want the last `\0`. Then:

```
std::copy(std::begin(d), std::end(d), std::begin(char_array));
```

Update: Apparently, the goal is to store this vector in another `uint8_t[8]`, if it's a variable named `foo`, just do:

```
std::copy(std::begin(d), std::end(d), std::begin(foo));
```

But check the length first... And pass the structure to populate as a reference. Also get a good C++ book.

Comment: Thanks, but I there is a struct that one of the members is `uint8_t Data[8];` and I want the string to be converted to `uint8_t` array because of that. so vector is not useful for me

Comment: In that case, forgo the vector, and just use the `std::copy`. It's still the proper answer to your problem. Creating an intermediate `char_array` as you are doing isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Since it seems from your comments that you have a compile time constant maximum size, I added a true array version:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <array>

struct foo {
    std::string& getData() {return mData;}
    const std::string& getData() const  {return mData;}
    std::vector<uint8_t> get_array() const {
        std::vector<uint8_t> array;
        std::copy(mData.cbegin(), mData.cend(), std::back_inserter(array));
        return array;
    };

    static constexpr size_t max_size = 8u;
    std::array<uint8_t, max_size> get_max_array() const {
        std::array<uint8_t, max_size> array;
        std::copy_n(mData.cbegin(), max_size, array.begin());
        return array;
    }

private:
    std::string mData;
};
```

Comment: Thanks but neither `vector` nor `std::array` is useful for me I want it in the form of `unint8_t []`

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi `std::array` does hold a `uint8_t[]`, why is that not useful?

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi Well sorry to break you the bad news but simple built in arrays like any `T[]` including `uint8_t[]`  won't work as expected, since built in arrays decay  to pointers. So you could only return a `uint8_t*` even if you are writing `[]`, and would have to work with much unsafer functions like new/malloc, strcpy or preprocessor macros. 

You can use `std:arrays` as any built in array via `.data()`

Comment: Well isn't that nice when you don't even get an upvote, because OP posted an AB problem...